# ResourceWarning: unclosed file error while running python selenium unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

While running python selenium unittest I'm seeing an error:

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py:605: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/newuser/scable/HTML_Test_Runner_ReportTest.html' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
  testMethod()
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.006s

OK
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 42230), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 34255)>
```

What does this error means?

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py:605: ResourceWarning: unclosed file
```

...implies that there was a *ResourceWarning* while trying to access an *unclosed file*.

---

This issue is specific to [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) as the *ResourceWarnings* are only emitted with *Python3*. The most probhable reason is, you have opened a file, used it, but then forgot to close the file. Though *Python* automatically closes the opened file on behalf of you when it notices that the file object is dead but this occurs after some significant time has elapsed.

This issue can also occur specifically on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) if you try to perform some operations in a file which is still open e.g. trying to delete a file.

However, this issue seems to arising as you try to open the file `HTML_Test_Runner_ReportTest.html` when the file was still under process.

A simple solution would be to wait for the `HTML_Test_Runner_ReportTest.html` file to be completely processed and then access it.

Comment: I tried by killing all the opened files and ran it again but getting same error

Comment: I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 with python 3.6.0 version ps -ef | grep .py
 4505  3693  0 13:23 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto .py  (I killed this process as well) but still getting same error, even i tried killing all the .html file but stll same error ps -ef | grep .html
newuser   4482  3693  0 13:22 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto .html     even I waited for 2 days still getting same error on 3rd day